# How to make object available to the job instance when it executes?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Here's an example of putting data into the `JobDataMap` prior to adding the job to the scheduler:

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DumbJob>()
    .UsingJobData("jobSays", "Hello World!")
    .UsingJobData("myFloatValue", 3.141f)
    .Build();
```

Getting values from a `JobDataMap`:

```
public class DumbJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
      JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
      string jobSays = dataMap.GetString("jobSays");
      float myFloatValue = dataMap.GetFloat("myFloatValue");
    }
}
```

But it works only with primitive types. So, I can't find the way to transfer `myObject` during the job's execution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DumbJob>()
    .UsingJobData("someKey", someObjectOfTypeT)
    .Build();


TypeT someValue = <TypeT>dataMap.Get("someKey");
```

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/

Comment: Where did u find "someObjectOfType"? There are only 8 constructors: (JobDataMap), (String, Boolean), (String, Decimal), (String, Double), (String, Int32), (String, Int64), (String, Single) and (String, String).